What's "walk into a test in a foreign-language class" mean?
This context comes from Malcolm Gladwell's book Outliers. I'm having difficulty understanding the passage in which he describes Christopher Langan, allegedly the smartest man in the world.

In school, Langan could walk into a test in a foreign-language class, not having studied at all, and if there were two or three minutes before the instructor arrived, he could skim through the textbook and ace the test.

First of all, I'm not sure whether a foreign-language class describes a period in school devoted to studying a language or a group of foreign students studying together.

a group of students or pupils who are taught together.
"selected pupils act as representatives for the whole class" (Oxford Languages)

an occasion when pupils meet with their teacher for instruction; a lesson.
"I was late for a class" (Oxford Languages)


I'm also not sure if "walk into" functions in  its literal sense here or means:

To enter some position, role, employment, etc., very easily or casually.
With that kind of experience and expertise, she'll be able to walk into any engineering job you want.
He walked right into a tenured position with the university because of his family's connections.


This is the second time I've edited one of your questions to use proper quote formatting. Please see what I did and use it for your future questions.

I haven't read the book, but the relevant sentence starts with In school,... which effectively forces the interpretation a period in school devoted to studying a language, since that initial "adverb of location" can only refer to the actual school the subject attends. It seems unlikely classes in Christopher Langan's school are attended by a group of foreign students studying together.

I think you are overthinking this.
Take a step back and think about what is being communicated here.  The important fact is that "Langan could pass a test in a foreign language after a very short amount of study."
This is surprising because most people find learning a foreign language very difficult and requires many hours of study.
The story might be a bit of an exaggeration. But "walk into" is meant literally. Taken literally it means that he could "enter a room where a class was about to take a foreign language test, without previously learning the language. Then casually read the textbook for two or three minutes, and then be able to get a high grade in the test."

In American English, "a foreign language class" as used here is a roomful of students who are taking a course in a particular foreign language.
The students could also be called "the class":

I am ordering a Fellini movie for the class to watch.

and it's also possible to have instruction outdoors:

Class, let's have class outdoors today. It's so nice outside.

but here Langan (literally) "walks into" the class, so the meaning is "roomful of students".
So, he could walk into such a roomful of students, skim the textbook for a few minutes, without having studied previously, and then get an "A" (top grade) on a test.

A test would be offered during a period of instruction but not by a group of students - "class" here uses the second definition, referring to a regular meeting or specific instance of students undergoing instruction together. The first definition you note is more in line with something like "senior class", which is a group of students who are in the same year but who don't necessarily take the exact same courses of instruction. One could walk into a "foreign language class" and take a test, but could not do that with the "senior class".
"Walk into" is used here rather literally, describing someone who enters the room, but context does give a connotation of simply doing it unannounced in a casual and calm manner. I suppose the phrasing might not necessarily be literal, as it would be a reasonable way to describe taking an online test as well, even though you don't literally "walk into" an online class.
Overall, the sentence describes someone casually entering a classroom where a test in a foreign language class is about to be held, and acing the test with virtually no preparation.
